# How to remove my app from iOS location under privacy settings

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I do not have a settings.bundle and i have factory reset my iphone 6 device.  Its running ios version 8.0

The issue is my app keeps appearing under settings. There is a privacy and then in that submenu appears location which is greyed out.  How do i remove this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your app use location services? All apps appear have their own Settings page even if you don't have a Settings bundle. It appears any time your app access the Internet via cellular, accesses any service protected by privacy, or uses notifications.

Comment: yes my app uses cellular but does not have notifications.  What call can i check in the app to see if its using location service?

Comment: Do you use `CLLocationManager`?

Comment: no, there is no call to CLLocationManager in my app.